# Run unit tests only on Windows

Tags: java, junit, junit-rule

I have a class that makes native Windows API calls through JNA.  How can I write JUnit tests that will execute on a Windows development machine but will be ignored on a Unix build server?

I can easily get the host OS using `System.getProperty("os.name")`

I can write guard blocks in my tests:

```
@Test public void testSomeWindowsAPICall() throws Exception {
  if (isWindows()) {
    // do tests...
  }
}
```

This extra boiler plate code is not ideal.

Alternatively I have created a JUnit rule that only runs the test method on Windows:

```
  public class WindowsOnlyRule implements TestRule {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description) {
      return new Statement() {
        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
          if (isWindows()) {
            base.evaluate();
          }
        }
      };
    }

    private boolean isWindows() {
      return System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows");
    }
  }
```

And this can be enforced by adding this annotated field to my test class:

```
@Rule public WindowsOnlyRule runTestOnlyOnWindows = new WindowsOnlyRule();
```

Both these mechanisms are deficient in my opinion in that on a Unix machine they will silently pass.  It would be nicer if they could be marked somehow at execution time with something similar to `@Ignore`

Does anybody have an alternative suggestion?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have you looked into assumptions?  In the before method you can do this:

```
@Before
public void windowsOnly() {
    org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(isWindows());
}
```

Documentation: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html

Comment: This is exactly the functionality I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

In Junit5, There are options for configuring or run the test for specific Operating System.

```
@EnabledOnOs({ LINUX, MAC })
void onLinuxOrMac() {

}

@DisabledOnOs(WINDOWS)
void notOnWindows() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for updating with the new junit feature, nice to know.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at JUnit [assumptions](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html) ?

> useful for stating assumptions about the conditions in which a test
>   is meaningful. A failed assumption does not mean the code is broken,
>   but that the test provides no useful information. The default JUnit
>   runner treats tests with failing assumptions as ignored

(which seems to meet your criteria for ignoring these tests).

Comment: @BrianAgnew using TestRules is the 2nd mechanism I have already described in my question.  I will take a look at assumptions.

Comment: I think  it's perhaps more appropriate in this scenario

Comment: @BrianAgnew Sorry I got a little grumpy.  I just thought I saw you edit the assumption piece in.

Comment: No problem. It's a fast moving site!

Answer (score 3):

If you use Apache Commons Lang's SystemUtils:
In your @Before method, or inside tests that you don't want to run on Win, you can add:

```
Assume.assumeTrue(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you do not need to actually call the Windows API as part of the junit test; you only care that the class which is the target of the unit test calls what it thinks is a the windows API.

Consider mocking the windows api calls as part of the unit tests.

Comment: I suspect he needs to call the Windows code *at some stage* and as such needs a Windows compatible test. I take your point re. mocking though and I'm sure there would be use for it somewhere

Comment: Yes I did consider mocking but in this case I do really want to call though to the underlying impl